# Posts are being redirected to xampp home page

Tags: posts, redirect

I have a wordpress site, I downloaded it from live and configured it on local using xampp. When i click on any post, it redirects me to `localhost/xampp` instead of post page
my .htaccess is like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_filter.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css application/x-javascript text/x-component text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "\.(css|js|htc|CSS|JS|HTC)$">
FileETag None
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.2.4"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|rtf|rtx|svg|svgz|txt|xsd|xsl|xml|HTML|HTM|RTF|RTX|SVG|SVGZ|TXT|XSD|XSL|XML)$">
FileETag None
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.2.4"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|wav|wma|wri|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip|ASF|ASX|WAX|WMV|WMX|AVI|BMP|CLASS|DIVX|DOC|DOCX|EOT|EXE|GIF|GZ|GZIP|ICO|JPG|JPEG|JPE|MDB|MID|MIDI|MOV|QT|MP3|M4A|MP4|M4V|MPEG|MPG|MPE|MPP|OTF|ODB|ODC|ODF|ODG|ODP|ODS|ODT|OGG|PDF|PNG|POT|PPS|PPT|PPTX|RA|RAM|SVG|SVGZ|SWF|TAR|TIF|TIFF|TTF|TTC|WAV|WMA|WRI|XLA|XLS|XLSX|XLT|XLW|ZIP)$">
FileETag None
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.2.4"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END W3TC Browser Cache
# BEGIN W3TC Page Cache core
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*\/)?w3tc_rewrite_test$ $1?w3tc_rewrite_test=1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_ENC:_gzip]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =highimpactdataindex.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (sitemap(_index)?\.xml(\.gz)?|[a-z0-9_\-]+-sitemap([0-9]+)?\.xml(\.gz)?) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\/wp-admin\/|\/xmlrpc.php|\/wp-(app|cron|login|register|mail)\.php|\/feed\/|wp-.*\.php|index\.php) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (wp\-comments\-popup\.php|wp\-links\-opml\.php|wp\-locations\.php) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\-postpass|wordpress_\[a\-f0\-9\]\+|wordpress_logged_in) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(W3\ Total\ Cache/0\.9\.2\.4) [NC]
RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/w3tc/pgcache/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_UA}%{ENV:W3TC_REF}%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" -f
RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/w3tc/pgcache/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_UA}%{ENV:W3TC_REF}%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" [L]
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Page Cache core
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Post your `.htaccess`. I am guessing there is a mismatch between that and your live setup. If you imported the database you could be seeing issues from that too.

Comment: @s_ha_dum plz see my edit

Comment: Disable caching while you try to deal with this. What is the url for your site on the Xampp server? I don't need to access it, which I can't, I just need to know what it is.

Comment: its is http://localhost/highimpact/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your rewrite rule is wrong. The existing rule is for when the site is at root-- `http://localhost`. You site is at `http://localhost/highimpact`. The final rewrite rule should, I believe, `RewriteRule . /highimpact/index.php [L]`.

If you go to wp-admin->Permalinks, and save the settings WordPress will rewrite the rules or tell you what the rules need to be if `.htaccess` isn't writable by the server. Try that, in case my guess is wrong.

I don't know what needs to happen with the cache rules. I would guess that the cache plugin has a similar mechanism for rewriting its rules but I don't how to get there.

Comment: yes it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you  took database from localhost. If so then go to phpmyadmin and click on wp_options table. at first line of that table you will see option_value "  localhost/directory" change it by your current site url.

Comment: There are two `option_name`s that need to be checked-- `siteurl` and `home`.

Comment: I have already made these changes in databases

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to yoursite/wp-admin Settings
2. Permalink Settings and change to Plain